# Use of type-parameters before a method/constructor in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I'm studying generics in Java, and was getting along comfortably until I reached the topic- ***Creating a generic method.***

I know that in Java, generics are used when you want to implement something irrespective of the data type that the program(or method) operates upon. So, you could have a ***generic class*** as `Class Gen<T>` and then in a non-generic class ***class GenDemo*** (which includes the `main()`). Then, you can create `Gen references` for different data types, such as `Gen<Integer> iOB` and `Gen <String> strOB`.

However, in the example given on creating a generic method, the book gives the following code:

```
//This is a simple generic method

class GenMethDemo
{

   //determine if an object is in an array
   static<T,V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y)
   {

      for (int i=0; i<y.length; i++)
          if(x.equals(y[i])) 
            return true;
          else
            return false;
   }

public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   //use isIn() on Integers
   Integer nums[]={1,2,3,4,5};

   if(isIn(2,nums))
   System.out.println("2 is in nums");

   if(!isIn(7,nums))
   System.out.println("2 is in nums");

   //use isIn() on Strings
   String strs[]={"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

   if(!(isIn("two", strs))
   System.out.println("two is in strs");

  }
}
```

I understand that this program is trying to determine if a given array consists of a specified object. But I can't wrap my head around this line:

```
static <T,V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y)
```

Thinking on the lines of what I've studied so far in generics, I know that there are two arguments of the Boolean function `isIn()`. But what are the ***type-paramaters*** `<T, V extends T>` doing before the return type of the function `isIn()`?

I understand the use of the keyword **extends** here; it acts as a **bound** for the **type-parameter** V, ie: V must be of the same type as T or a subclass of T, but I can't get further.

There is a similar use of type-parameters under the topic: ***Creating Generic Constructors***, as:

```
class GenCons
    {
       private double val;

       <T extends Number> GenCons(T arg)
          {
             val=arg.doubleValue();
          }

        void showVal()
          {
            System.out.println("Val: "+ val); 
          }

    }
```

As before, I'm stumped by the line: `<T extends Number> GenCons(T arg)`. Why is `<T extends Number>` used before the constructor is declared? It could also have been written like: `GenCons(<T extends Number> arg)`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me where did you get the example of "Creating Generic Constructors"?

Answer (score 0):

Notice how in your `GenMethDemo` and `GenCons` classes, the class itself doesn't have a generic type. It's not `class GenMethDemo<T, V extends T>` -- instead, it's just `class GenMethDemo`.

So if `GenMethDemo` and `GenCons` aren't generic classes, how are you able to use generics? It seems to be a contradiction.

Well, Java also lets you define **generic methods**. If I do `static<T,V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y)`, it's as if I had actually done `class GenMethDemo<T, V extends T>` except that the type variables `T` and `V` are scoped only to that particular method. This can be useful when you don't necessarily want the entire class to use generics; only a method or two where they're really needed.